# Swift: CoreData NSManagedObject Subclass Prefix

Tags: core-data, swift, prefix

I have read the Apple documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/WritingSwiftClassesWithObjective-CBehavior.html) regarding prefixing the **App Name** or the target name in all ManagedObject's class in order to work.

For example I have an app named SwiftApp then my managedObject sub class name in object modeller should be:

Say, I have `User` then `SwiftApp.User`

say, I have `Car` then `SwiftApp.Car`

My question is, how would you do it if the core data is in a framework? What would be the prefix to be used? Is it the framework name?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The prefix they are talking about is actually a 3 letter prefix i.e `ALLSwiftApp` (`ALL` taken from `Allan`)

For the Core Data part when you click on an `Entity` in your `.xcdatamodeld`

[image]

You can add your Prefix in the `Class` field.